# Tem crase em "análoga a acima"?

Tags: crase

Nunca vi a palavra "acima" com o acento grave, mas --- da mesma forma que se craseia a palavra "aquela" ---, parece a mim também que se deve crasear a palavra "acima" quando a regência nominal determina, como é o caso da regência de "analógo a".  Por exemplo, em "produza uma tabela análoga a acima", penso que se poderia escrever "análoga àcima".  Dito isso, meu senso de estética parece dizer que "análoga a acima" soa melhor.

**Pergunta**.  O que diz a teoria e o que se faz nesse caso?  Obrigado.

Comment: à é crase. ácima não existe, sejamos claros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Também me parece estranho com crase em "acima", provavelmente porque quando escrevemos ou dizemos

> a acima

o substantivo está implícito:

> a [tabela] acima

Ou seja, assim como escreveríamos

> um processo análogo ao [processo] descrito acima

creio que se escreva:

> produza uma tabela análoga à acima

embora eu preferisse:

> produza uma tabela análoga àquela acima

Também suspeito que o fato de "acima" não ser substantivo ou pronome (é um advérbio) é um empecilho ao uso da crase — mas não encontro uma fundamentação para essa hipótese.

Comment: Sua observação de que "acima" não é um substantivo ilumina bastante a questão aqui.  Tipicamente não começamos uma frase dizendo algo como "A acima [...]" porque "acima" não é substantivo, como você bem observa.  Similarmente, o artigo "a" viria de "a tabela" e daí sim teríamos "análoga à (tabela) acima".  Muito bem observado.  Concluo assim que não teremos crase na palavra "acima" pela razão de não ser um substantivo.  Muito obrigado pela iluminante análise na questão.